# How to add red border to checkboxes when not valid in Contact Form 7

Tags: validation, contact-form-7

I hope someone can help. I need to add a red border to checkboxes to indicate that they are required fields and need to be checked prior to being able to submit a form.

I would also like error messages to show immediately if the field has been completed incorrectly - can someone please let me know how to do this? I.e. If I haven't entered anything in the first field, it won't let me move onto the next field unless the previous one has been completed properly and an error message will appear below the field to state this. I.e. "Please enter your name" to prompt the user.

I have made the border with the regular text fields (using the below), but don't know how to add to the checkboxes field:

```
}
span .wpcf7-not-valid {
    border: 3px solid #ff0000 !important;
}
```

I hope someone can help, many thanks in advance :)